# Compare a string from $_GET with a string from an array

Tags: php, arrays, string, foreach, compare

This has been frustrating me, because I'm pretty new to PHP and am sure I'm missing something very basic about the nature of the language. But why oh why won't this work?

```
$tag = $_GET['id'];
$openfile = fopen($files[$i], "r");
$tagsraw = fgets($openfile);
$tag_array = explode(",",$tagsraw);
foreach ($tag_array as $a) {
    if ($a == $tag) {
        echo $a." matches ".$tag;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** The file-opening works fine, by the way; `print_r()` shows that `$tag_array` populates how it's meant to.

**EDIT:** Here's the printout from `print_r()`. There are five files, and each has its tags in the first line.

```
Array
(
    [0] => webdesign

)
Array
(
    [0] => personal

)
Array
(
    [0] => recipes
    [1] => vegan

)
Array
(
    [0] => personal

)
Array
(
    [0] => personal

)
```

Comment: Where is the rest of your code, what's in `$files` ?

Comment: what's in the `id` get parameter?  Also, are you sure there aren't any trailing or leading spaces in any of those tags?

Comment: `$files` is an array containing paths to .txt files, and `fopen()` and `fget()` both work how they're meant to. I can post the rest of the code if you need, I was just hoping that I'd made some glaringly obvious gaff in these few lines.

Comment: Possible values of `$tag_array` or at least some bytes of the files which will be opened would be fine.

Comment: `id` is, for instance, `personal` or `recipes` or `webdesign` or something. The files are not single-line, but the tags are in the first line. I'm pretty sure there aren't any spaces, I'll run `trim()` and check.

Comment: Start using `var_dump` to see what's in each of the variables Try `var_dump($_GET); var_dump($tag_array);`. Add an `else` onto your if-statement to see when it fails. Try changing it to `if (trim($a) == trim($tag))`.

Comment: Ah! `trim()` worked. I feel a wee bit silly now, for not doing that before.

Answer (score 4):

my magic crystal ball tells me that "doesn't work" means

```
if ($a == $tag) {
```

is never true?

you probably have whitespace characters around one of them. use [var_dump](http://www.php.net/var_dump)() to inspect the values of variables. Notice that var_dump tells you the data type, and for strings, the string length in bytes.

If there is whitespace, you can remove it using PHP's `trim` function:

```
if (trim($a) == trim($tag)) {
```

Comment: +1 for noting that a magic crystal ball is necessary for answering this question.

Comment: Hope you don't mind that I added a solution to your answer. You thought of it first. Doesn't seem right to re-answer and steal your rep.